# Dumping Image data and load using pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, image, pytorch

I want to dump the data so that I can load it back for training my model.

My code snipped for dumping the data:

```
for batch_idx, (image, label) in enumerate(dataloader):
    image, label = image.to(device), label.to(device)
    perturbed_image = attack.perturb(image, label)
    
    #---------- Classifier ----------
    predict_A = classifier(perturbed_image)
    pred_label = torch.max(predict_A.data, 1)[1]
    
    if pred_label != label:
        adv_data.append( (perturbed_image.to("cpu"), label.to("cpu")) )
```

Is there any other way I can dump it correctly so as to load it in the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straight forward approach would be to use [`torch.save`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.save.html#torch.save) to save the actual tensors of `perturbed_image` and `label` as binary files, and then use a [custom `Dataset`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504871/1714410). Note that the saved tensors are *not* single image/label, but rather batches of images/labels. Your new custom `Dataset` should account for it.

Comment: Thank you @Shai. Can you please provide a code snippet of how would I use custom Dataset to load it to the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.

Comment: @x2212 please look at the linked answer